# On the difference between double and ordinary limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Limit_of_function) gives us two notions of the multivariate limit of a function ( as distinct from the *iterated* limits of a function). The first, which it calls an *ordinary* limit is denoted

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y) $$ and is defined in the usual way: i.e this limit exists and is equal to $L$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t } \lVert(x,y)-(a,b) \rVert_2 < \delta \implies \lvert f(x,y) - L \rvert <\epsilon .$

The second type of limit, which it calls a *double* limit is denoted
$$\lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} x \to a \\ y \to b \end{smallmatrix}}f(x,y)$$ and is said to exist and equal $L$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } \lvert x - a \rvert < \delta \text{ and } \lvert y - b \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x,y) - L \rvert < \epsilon $.

The article says the former is a stronger notion than the latter but I fail to appreciate the difference as the second definition just seems to use the infinity norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than the $L^2$ norm. Since norms are equivalent in this setting, I’m not quite sure why the former is stronger.

Comment: The sequential equivalent of the 1st limit is that you can approach the point however you wish as long as you avoid being at the point during the approach. The sequential equivalent of the 2nd limit is that you can approach the point however you wish as long as you avoid having $x$-coordinate of $a$ and avoid having $y$-coordinate of $b$ during the approach.

Comment: What you wrote in the definitions in the question body  differs significantly from your source in Wikipedia, because you omit condition of strict greater than zero for variables. In such formulations definitions are equivalent. For confirming Wikipedia, or more, Zakon book Mathematical analysis 1, mentioned there, one need counter example, because Stewart,  Multivariable Calculus, consider both notations as same.

Comment: Indeed, since $0 < \lVert (x,y) - (a,b)\rVert_\infty < \delta$ does not imply $0< \lvert x - a \rvert < \delta $ and $ 0 < \lvert y - b  \rvert < \delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write mentioned in comments counter example as answer. Of course, I am speaking about Wikipedia definitions comparison (not those which are in question body) i.e. lets define notation $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=L$ as
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \text{ s.t } 0< \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}  < \delta \implies \lvert f(x,y) - L \rvert <\varepsilon \quad(1)$$
and  notation  $\lim\limits_{\begin{smallmatrix} x \to a \\ y \to b \end{smallmatrix}}f(x,y)=L$  with second definition
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } 0<\lvert x - a \rvert < \delta, 0<\lvert y - b \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x,y) - L \rvert < \varepsilon \quad(2)$$
These defintions also can be found in book Zakon E. - Mathematical analysis 1-Trillia Group, 2004, pages 150 and 219. As in Wikipedia, so in Zakon's book, is theorem that $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$. As counter example let me bring function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1, & x=a \text{ or } y=b, \\
0, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$
Then, obviously $(2)$ holds for $L=0$, while $(1)$ not exists.